# indefinite integral of alternating series

Tags: analysis

Define

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{{(-1)^k}{{(2015x)}^{2k}}}\over{{((2k)!)}^2}}\\ \\ $$
Evaluate: 
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}f(x)dx\\$$

My attempt:

By alternating series test, f(x) converges in its radius of convergence has [$-1\over2015$,$1\over2015$] contained in it. In fact the convergence is uniform on this interval because of the following and Weierstrass M test.

$(2k)! > 2^{2k-1}, |f(x)|< \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{{{(2015x)}^{2k}}}\over{{(2)}^{4k-2}}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{{1}\over{{(2)}^{4k-2}}}\\$

Thus we can divide the integral as $$\int_0^{1/2015}e^{-x}f(x)dx +\int_{1/2015}^{\infty}e^{-x}f(x)dx\\$$

Summation and integral can be interchanged for the first integral however it doesn't simplify it considerably. Besides I am not sure how to deal with the second integral.

I also tried integrating by parts but I get two terms one of which is $cos(2015)$ and the other one is unsolvable.

Comment: Look at $$g(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(2015 x)^{2k}}{\bigl((2k)!\bigr)^2}.$$ Is $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} g(x)\,dx < +\infty$? If it is, how does that help?

Comment: The radius of convergence for that power series is $\infty.$ Go at this with   the DCT or MCT and @DanielFischer's comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer You should give an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k (2015 x)^{2 k}}{((2 k)!)^2} \, dx=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k e^{-x} ( x)^{2 k}}{((2 k)!)^2} \, dx$$
Bringing out of the integral sign all the stuff which doesn't depend on $x$
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \,2015^{2k}}{((2 k)!)^2} \int_0^{\infty } e^{-x}  x^{2 k} \, dx$$
Note that the integral is the Laplace transform of $x^{2 k}$ when $s=1$
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-sx} x^{2 k} \, dx=\mathcal{L}_x\left[x^{2 k}\right](s)=\frac{(2 k)!}{s^{2 k+1}}$$
so that 
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x} x^{2 k} \, dx= (2 k)!$$
back to the series
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{((2 k)!)^2} 2015^{2 k} (2 k)!=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k 2015^{2 k}}{(2 k)!}=\color{red}{\cos 2015}\approx-0.32564$$

The series of functions converges absolutely in all $\mathbb{R}$ because of the ratio test
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \frac{4060225 x^2 ((2 k)!)^2}{((2 k+2)!)^2}=-\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \frac{4060225 x^2}{4 (k+1)^2 (2 k+1)^2}=0$$
For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k}
> \pars{2015x}^{2k} \over \bracks{\pars{2k}!}^{2}}.\qquad
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

Note that
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k}
\pars{2015x}^{2k} \over \bracks{\pars{2k}!}^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2015x\ic}^{2k} \over \bracks{\pars{2k}!}^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{
\pars{2015x\ic}^{k} \over \pars{k!}^{2}}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2015x\ic}^{k} \over \pars{k!}^{2}} =
\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k!}^{2}}\
\overbrace{k!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{1/2015}^{\Large \color{#f00}{-}}}{\expo{2015xz\ic} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\pars{2015x\ic}^{k}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{1/2015}^{\Large \color{#f00}{-}}}
{\expo{2015xz\ic} \over z}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{1/z}^{k} \over k!}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{1/2015}^{\Large \color{#f00}{-}}}{\expo{2015xz\ic}\expo{1/z} \over z}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ \pars{1/2015}^{\Large \color{#f00}{-}}}
{1 \over 1 - 2015z\ic}\,{\expo{1/z} \over z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,
\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 2015^{\Large \color{#f00}{+}}}
{\expo{z} \over \pars{1 - 2015\ic/z}/z}\,{\dd z/z^{2} \over 2\pi\ic} =
\Re\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 2015^{\Large \color{#f00}{+}}}
{\expo{z} \over z - 2015\ic}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\exp\pars{2015\ic} = \bbx{\cos\pars{2015}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The dominated convergence Theorem allows us to exchange $\int$ and $\sum$ in

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k 2015^{2k} x^{2k}}{(2k)!^2}\,dx = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k 2015^{2k}}{(2k)!^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2k}e^{-x}\,dx $$
and get that the wanted integral equals
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k 2015^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \color{blue}{\cos(2015)}. $$

Comment: Do you know by heart the value of integrals like $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2k}e^{-x}\,dx\quad$  ?? :)

Comment: @Raffaele: isn't $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^n e^{-x}\,dx = n!$ taught in pre-school? :D